# JavaScript Save element as image or Extjs 4.x Save as image

Tags: javascript, image, extjs, save

I would like to know if there is a way to save Extjs Panel's content as an image ? I did do that with print but now I want to save it as image instead of print it out.

or just a way to save element as image in javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there's **[HTML2Canvas project](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/)**

For more infos, read **[this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots)**.

Comment: Thanks! thats is great fro take screenshots. but what about save it dynamically ?!

Comment: @Noon What do you mean with 'save it dynamically'?

Comment: I mean when user takes the screen shot, how he would save it ?

Comment: @Noon Honestly, I don't know. I only knew of HTML2Canvas project but I didn't use it. Have you read the documentation and tried any tests?